# yii2 cannot access root subfolder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

I'm really bad at htaccess setting and would like to have some help with it. I have a project inside a subfolder, and can be opened like this: www.mydomain.com/subfolder/. I put my project inside "subfolder". "subfolder" is not a subdomain, I just simply created a new folder in root folder.

I can open home page, but all other page like www.mydomain.com/subfolder/about, www.mydomain.com/subfolder/product have 500 internal server error page. I also can't access uploaded file in uploads folder, so URL like www.domain.com/subfolder/uploads/filename.jpg will return error 404. I'm pretty sure that there is no php error becase I also uploaded it in my other subdomain (different domain) and it works fine.

This is my htaccess setting:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/font/(.*)$ backend/web/font/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/plugins/(.*)$ backend/web/plugins/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/images/(.*)$ backend/web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|font|plugins|images|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|fonts|uploads)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/web/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ frontend/web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|img|images|fonts|uploads|plugins|font)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please show your config properties. It looks like you `baseUrl` definitions are wrong.

Comment: You also might need to reconfigure your urlManager to process such links - it looks like routing problem of yii2, not apache.

Answer (score 0):

After i check the script, i found some different in the code. 
And i try to fixing some code like this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/font/(.*)$ backend/web/font/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/img/(.*)$ backend/web/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/plugins/(.*)$ backend/web/plugins/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|font|img|js|plugins)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|font|img|js|uploads)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^font/(.*)$ frontend/web/font/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/web/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ frontend/web/uploads/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|font|img|js|uploads|plugins)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php [L]
```

There are some sign i add that is this sign ( ^ ).
And for uploading file (image, js, css, etc) i recommend you to upload to folder backend/web/somefolder or frontend/web/somefolder. Put beside those two place, for images, makes your images can not show on all over the place (in my experience).
And also, you can try to make the folder inside **frontend/web/** or **backend/web/** the same name, so that can makes you easier to remember (please see the code that i fix to see what i mean). I hope it helps for others.

If someone have the better solution, please share it here. Thanks.